# Find inverse function for the following

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What's the inverse function of $f(x)=x+Int(x)$

I can't do it algebraically, but by drawing the picture and reflects it by y=x

I get something like $f(x)=x-n$  $x\in [2n, 2n+1]$ $ n\in N$

Is that right? If so, what's the algebraic way to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $Int(x)$ rounds down, then $Int(x+Int(x))$ must be even and equal to $2Int(x)$

so $g(y) = y - \dfrac{Int(y)}{2}$ is the inverse of $f(x)=x+Int(x)$

Comment: Note that $f(x)$ is not the inverse of $g(y)$: for example $g(3.6) = 2.1$ but $f(2.1)=4.1\not = 3.6$ though you also have $g(4.1)=2.1$

Comment: But, after I draw the picture, I think the domain of $g(x)$ is not $R$